# R: Why is pmap not working while map2 does?

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, purrr, pmap

I am fairly new to R and am teaching myself some machine learning techniques. Currently I am working on hyperparameter tuning and to get a better understanding of the matter I try to do the tasks more manually than they need to be. So I am using a tibble with list columns where each row contains among other things a training set cross-validation fold and certain hyperparameter values of a random forest algorithm. The whole grid contains all unique combinations of these in a specified range. 
The models should be built by iterating the `ranger` function over all rows(i.e. fold/parameter combinations) and then be saved into a list column. For this purpose I use the map function family of the purrr package.

The problem is that this approach only works when mapping the data and one single parameter(**mtry**) to the `ranger` function by using `map2`. I know that I need to use `pmap` when mapping more than 2 elements to a function. But this, unlike the two element case described before, does not work for me with data and two parameters(**mtry and min.node.size**) as elements. The `pmap` function is somehow not able to map the third element(**min.node.size**) as argument to the `ranger` function and I get the following error:

*"Error in ranger(Species ~ ., data = .x, mtry = .y, min.node.size = .z) : 
  object '.z' not found"*

This is my code using the iris data set:

```
### used packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ranger)
library(rsample)

### data preparation
set.seed(123)

initial_split_data <- initial_split(iris, prop = 0.8)

training <- training(initial_split_data)
testing <- testing(initial_split_data)

cv_split <- vfold_cv(training, v = 3)

cv_data <- cv_split %>% 
  mutate(train = map(.x = splits, .f = ~training(.x)),
         validate = map(.x = splits, .f = ~testing(.x)),
         validate_species = map(.x = validate, .f = ~.x$Species))

### modeling
## two elements being mapped works:
random_forest_model_mtry <- cv_data %>% 
  crossing(mtry = seq(2,4,1)) %>% 
  mutate(model = map2(.x = train, .y = mtry, 
                                    .f = ~ranger(Species ~., data = .x, mtry = .y)))


## three elements being mapped does not work:
random_forest_model_mtry_minnode <- cv_data %>% 
  crossing(mtry = seq(2,4,1),
           min.node.size = seq(1,5,1)) %>% 
  mutate(model = pmap(list(.x = train, .y = mtry, .z = min.node.size), 
                                    .f = ~ranger(Species ~., data = .x, mtry = .y, min.node.size = .z)))
```

It would be really helpful if someone could show me how to correctly use `pmap` in this case so that the random forest models get executed.

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `?pmap` help page:

> ```
>  .f: A function, formula, or vector (not necessarily atomic).
>
>      If a *function*, it is used as is.
>
>      If a *formula*, e.g. ‘~ .x + 2’, it is converted to a
>      function. There are three ways to refer to the arguments:
>
>        • For a single argument function, use ‘.’
>
>        • For a two argument function, use ‘.x’ and ‘.y’
>
>        • For more arguments, use ‘..1’, ‘..2’, ‘..3’ etc
> ```

For multiple arguments, we need to replace `.x`, `.y`, etc. with `..1`, `..2`, etc.:

```
random_forest_model_mtry_minnode <- cv_data %>% 
    crossing(mtry = seq(2,4,1),min.node.size = seq(1,5,1)) %>% 
    mutate(model = pmap(list(train, mtry, min.node.size), 
                        .f = ~ranger(Species ~., data = ..1, 
                                     mtry = ..2, min.node.size = ..3)))
```

Note that elements of the argument list (`list(train, mtry, min.node.size)` in your case) can be unnamed. What matters is their order, as that is what gets referenced by `..1`, `..2`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was extremely useful.